# Create a filter for a slicer based on if the sum of values is not equal to zero when a timeline changes

Tags: excel, powerpivot, slicers

I have a general question about how to set up a slicer used with several power pivot charts. I have two charts that share a timeline and display company totals and I have a slicer that allows for individual vendors to be selected.

Everything works as intended, the only problem is that for this report a logical timeframe to look at would be a year or less, and in that timeframe we likely have done business with 200 to 300 vendors.  The slicer holds all of our vendors which is almost 2000.

This makes finding a specific vendor more difficult and the vast majority of options include no data as the vendors history only exists outside of the selected timeframe.

Is there a way to filter the contents of the vendor slicer by sum(payables.total) <> 0

Thanks, any suggestions will be appreciated

**EDIT:**

So I do have a working solution however it seems like I'm using a lot of unnecessary steps, however with no solutions suggested I will add this in case it is actually the optimal choice.

1. Added a global variable "universal value on all lines"  to my data model table and named the column "site"
2. Created a new table named DATE_SELECT, it has three columns, `fromDate`, `toDate` and `site`, where the dates can be selected and the site column value is fixed and equal to the global variable value in the data model.
3. Added the new table to the datamodel and created a one to many relationship on "site"
4. I used the below formula to create a calculated column that compares the invoice date to the selected dates in the new table and return the vendor name when invoice date is between the selected dates. I named it `Vendor2`

   ```
   =IF(AND(AP_2[INVOICE_DATE] >= RELATED(DATE_SELECT[FROM_DATE]), AP_2[INVOICE_DATE] <= RELATED(DATE_SELECT[TO_DATE])), AP_2[NAME], "")
   ```
5. In my charts I added `Vendor2` as a filter and unselected null, this now works as my new date filter.
6. I added the new slicer using `Vendor2`, it still has a null value but all out range vendors are now categorized into this single field.

So now rather than using the time line the user can select two dates to establish a date range and then refresh all and both the charts and the vendor slicer update dynamically as desired.

Again, it just seems like this cant be the simplest solution so please let me know if there is a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: I normally use "Hide Items with no data" in slicer settings. Is it not working for you for some reasons?

Comment: Not as I would like at least, we do have vendors that have been set up for quotes but that have never been used, they have a null value in payables and they are being filtered out.  What I cant seem to get working is where there is a null value in the selected timeframe.  The slicer still shows all venors that have any payables history disregarding the timeline selection.